# How to get parent of WebElement

Tags: java, selenium

I've tried

```
private WebElement getParent(final WebElement webElement) {
    return webElement.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
}
```

But I'm getting:

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector .. is
>   either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error
>   occurred:
> InvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression
>   ".." is: [object XrayWrapper [object HTMLDocument]]. It
>   should be an element.
> Command duration or timeout: 10
>   milliseconds
> For documentation on this error,

Is there a way to get the parent of current element? Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me. Something else must be going on. Post more code.

Comment: Your approach seems to be fine. Post an HTML code sample, where you get your error please

Answer (score 29):

There are a couple of ways you can accomplish this. If you insist on using XPath to do it, you need to add the context node to the locator, like this:

```
WebElement parentElement = childElement.findElement(By.xpath("./.."));
```

Alternatively, you can use the `JavascriptExecutor` interface, which might be slightly more performant. That would look like this:

```
// NOTE: broken into separate statements for clarity. Could be done as one statement.
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement parentElement = (WebElement)executor.executeScript("return arguments[0].parentNode;", childElement);
```

Comment: thanks ,workking perfect for me!

Comment: Simple but genius to use the child element's parent code to go up two levels to get the parent. NICE.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, can you try using Javascript Executor?

```
WebElement childElement = driver.findElement(By.id("someIdHere"));

WebElement parent = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
.executeScript("return arguments[0].parentNode;", childElement);
```