# How to get parent id from current id in Selenium + Java

Tags: java, selenium

```html
<ul id="ul_id">
  <li id="f_li"><a href="#">First li</a>
    <ul id="f_li_ul_id">
      <li id="li_ul_li1"><a href="#">First li ul li</a></li>
      <li id="li_ul_li2"><a href="#">Second li ul li</a></li>
      <li id="li_ul_li3"><a href="#">Third li ul li</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="s_li"><a href="#">Second li</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to get f_li_ul_id from my current id li_ul_li2 and get ul_id from my current id s_li.

Comment: Try to find your answer in this Article:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267413/how-to-get-parent-of-webelement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267413/how-to-get-parent-of-webelement)

Comment: i tried that my xpath is printing with /.. is not getting parent node

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select parent element of known element in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577636/select-parent-element-of-known-element-in-selenium)

Comment: see the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45769799/8179099

Comment: The simplest way is like, `//ul[./li[@id='li_ul_li2']]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reach at `f_li_ul_id` from `li_ul_li2` , you can use this xpath :

```
//li[@id='li_ul_li2']/parent::ul[@id='f_li_ul_id']
```

and for `ul_id` from `s_li`, you can write xpath like this :

```
//li[@id='s_li']/parent::ul[@id='ul_id']
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu-item-1164']/parent::ul")) i tried this my out put is [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (372c9e1f4b57203ec23742b80150fd61)] -> xpath: //*[@id='menu-item-1164']/parent::ul]

Comment: i want to get dynamically parent ul id without entering parent ul id

Comment: I don't see any element with this id : `menu-item-1164`

Comment: then try with this: `//li[@id='li_ul_li2']/..` , it should give you parent irrespective of ul id.

Comment: i tried that also output is [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (372c9e1f4b57203ec23742b80150fd61)] -> xpath: //*[@id='menu-item-1164']/..]

Comment: the id you are using is dynamic : `menu-item-1164` , it may be changing during the  run time. Is URL public ?

Comment: For this post i have created dummy ul li that id is from live project

Comment: How to get parent ul id dynamically?

Comment: If you are at the current node just use `/..`  to get to the parent node.

Comment: It's simply printing like /.. this only not getting parent node. can you show me how to display parent id?

Comment: See, if you are using `String id_value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='li_ul_li2']/..")).getAttribute('id')` , you should be able to get this when you print `id_value` : `f_li_ul_id`

Comment: see, my html code is <ul id="menu"><li id="1153"><a href="#">some text</a><ul class="submenu"><li id="1164"><a href="#">some text</a></li></ul></li></ul> from this using id 1164 i want to get 1153 id dynamically as of now i am getting class="submenu" from above code you have given

Comment: oh that's easy , just use /.. one more time :  `//li[@id='li_ul_li2']/../..` , let me know if this isn't working for you

Comment: Thanks that is working fine but now the issue is i am trying to use that string inside moveToElement that is showing error